# Data is loaded from server but isn't added to arraylist

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have the following situation: my program downloads data from server and after adds it to `ArrayList`.

```
static List<Film> generateFilms(){
        Log.i(Tag, "In generate films");
        List <Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/";
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original =  chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "auth-value");
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        APIService apiService  = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        final Call<Film> filmsCall = apiService.getFilms();
        filmsCall.enqueue(new Callback<Film>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Film> call, @NonNull Response<Film> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Film film = response.body();
                    films.add(film);
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response: "+Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getTitle());
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Film> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t);
            }
        });

        Log.i(Tag, "Size = "+films.size());
        return films;
    }
```

But it does it in a strange manner: it firstly returns an array and then gets the data (as I see from logs). Here's the logs:

```
2019-04-01 22:00:06.766 4974-4974/asus.example.com.exercise5 I/DataUtil: In generate films
2019-04-01 22:00:06.889 4974-4974/asus.example.com.exercise5 I/DataUtil: Size = 0
2019-04-01 22:00:07.367 4974-4974/asus.example.com.exercise5 I/DataUtil: Response: Batman
```

So, how can I solve this problem, as I need to get data firstly and then return the array?

Answer (score 0):

`Call<T>.enqueu()` acts in asynchronous way, so you can't return data from `generateFilms` method itself but only make all required actions in `onResponse` or create custom callback.

Sample:

```
interface OnLoaded {
  void onLoaded(Film film);
}

void generateFilms(OnLoaded callback) {
  ...
 filmsCall.enqueue(new Callback<Film>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Film> call, @NonNull Response<Film> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Film film = response.body();
                    mFilms.add(film);
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response: "+Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getTitle());

                    callback.onLoaded(film);
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());
                }
            }
```

And use it:

```
private List<Film> mFilms = new ArrayList<Film>();  // class-level field

generateFilms(new OnLoaded() {
  @Override
  public void onLoaded(Film film) {
    mFilms.add(film);
    // do actions with film or mFilms if you need
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. It still returns empty array. Elements are added after return.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the way you want to populate your `List`. Anyway, if you want to make **synchronous** request, reference this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests. Hope it helps